# Error Cannot find module , testing Nestjs Services

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm having a hard time with testing services on Nestjs, i believe is something related to my lack of knowledge on how the dependency injection works for tests, weird thing is only getting errors on the test. I have 3 modules Teste, Teste2, Teste3, Teste2 imports Teste3 service, and Teste imports Teste2 service. I tried exporting Teste2 and Teste3, and importing their modules, works fine when i run npm start. Doesnt work on the test thought...

Teste

```
 @Module({
    imports: [],
    providers: [ TesteService,Teste2Service],
    exports: [TesteService],
    controllers: [TesteController]
  })
  export class TesteModule {}
@Injectable()
export class TesteService {
constructor(private teste2Service: Teste2Service){}

    teste(){
        return this.teste2Service.hello();
    }
}
```

Teste2

```
@Module({
  imports: [Teste3Module],
  providers: [Teste2Service],
  exports: [Teste2Service]
})
export class Teste2Module {}
@Injectable()
export class Teste2Service {
    constructor(private teste3Service: Teste3Service){}
    hello(){
        return this.teste3Service.hello();
    }
}
```

Teste3

```
@Module({
  providers: [Teste3Service],
  exports: [Teste3Service]
})
export class Teste3Module {}

@Injectable()
export class Teste3Service {

    hello(){
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

the actual test

```
describe('TesteService', () => {
  let service: TesteService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports:[Teste2Module],
      providers: [TesteService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<TesteService>(TesteService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

The error 
src/teste/teste.service.spec.ts

```
Cannot find module 'src/teste2/teste2.service' from 'teste.service.ts'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

E2E cannot find absolute path.
Change to relative path: ../src/teste2

Comment: Is there a way of reusing the nest alias? This fixed my e2e test, but still failing while importing the AppModule, which depends on a `@shared` lib

Comment: You can config the paths in tsconfig file -> compilerOptions.
Something like that:
"paths": {
     "@apis/*": ["src/apis/*"]
}